# Change value of getAttribute when null

Tags: javascript

I am creating a document that contains the selected answers from a quiz.

I am running into trouble when some questions are skipped based on previous answers. When this occurs, I receive,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'getAttribute')

How can I amend my code to pass a value of "N/A" when the field is skipped? I have tried the following with no avail.

```
var oldValue = document.querySelector(".quiz_selected_answer input[name='question-2']").getAttribute('data-value');
            var newValue; 
            if (!oldValue) { 
                newValue =  
                "N/A"; 
            } else { 
                newValue = oldValue; 
            }
```

Thank you community for your help. It is appreciated.

Comment: `let newValue = oldValue || "N/A";`

Comment: @ChrisG: But isn't the error occurring when `oldValue` is determined?

Comment: You are right, what he needs to do is get the element only without the .`getAttribute()` yet. Then do something like `if (oldValue.hasAttribute('data-value')){` assuming that your element doesn't even have that attribute when skipped

Comment: *reading 'getAttribute'* indicates that the element `document.querySelector(...)` is attempting to retrieve doesn't exist. @Bill should include the html as well and determine why the selector isn't finding anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the error happens on this line:

```
var oldValue = document.querySelector(".quiz_selected_answer input[name='question-2']").getAttribute('data-value');
```

Then it doesn't matter what changes you make *after* this line, the error will prevent the code from ever reaching those changes.

You could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
var oldValue = document.querySelector(".quiz_selected_answer input[name='question-2']")?.getAttribute('data-value');
//                                                         here >----------------------^
```

Then instead of throwing an error it would just assign `undefined` to `oldValue`, which is ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and should satisfy the rest of the code.

Comment: Solved with a single character! How often does that happen!? Adding the "?" did in fact make the value "N/A" when not selected. THANK YOU for this.